# restart mysql database when full

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, restart, diskspace

I have a remote MYSQL database and it was filling up with data, so I was busy deleting data via mysql workbench when I lost the connection and was unable to connect to that table again. I shut down and restarted the server, however it would not restart.

1. The server status is now stopped (`MYSQLD is stopped`)
2. When I try to start the server the status is `MYSQL Daemon failed to start`
3. I ran the `df -h` command and I have no available space
4. I know I need to create space to allow the daemon to start up. I could call the hosting service and pay for more space, but that would be a waste, as I would only need it to delete data
5. Is there a way to delete data out of a table without starting the daemon? I want to create enough space to start and then delete data to keep it under the size limitations. If need be I would be prepared to drop one table to restart the database. How do I do that given that MYSQL wont start?

Answer (score 0):

you can't delete data from a table without starting the server, but you can delete a table without starting the server ( but i don't think is what you want )

try to find a log file, that maybe you don't need like, or some other files
this command will search your entire server for a file bigger that 100 MB

```
find / -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the find command and found some files that were bigger than 100 MB. I then removed the log files from the server which created enough space to restart the server. I then used TRUNCATE to reduce the size of the database as it does not create temporary backup files as DELETE does. The DELETE command needs temporary storage which I didn't have a lot of. DB is back up and running. Thankyou.